# Copying binary file using more than 1 buffer causes wrong md5 checksum

Tags: c, file

I have 1 file say abc.exe
When i read the file using fread into a buffer and directly write out from that buffer itself using fwrite, my output file has correct md5 checksum.
When i copy the file to an intermediate buffer, i get a different md5 checksum but same file size as original.
FILE_BLOCK_SIZE is 1000

```
  memset(BufContent, '\0', sizeof(BufContent));
  while ((BufContentSz = fread(BufContent, sizeof(unsigned char), FILE_BLOCK_SIZE, fin)) > 0) 
  {
    //ignore sum lines, merely for checking
    //sum+=(int)strlen(BufContent);
    //sum2+=BufContentSz;
    unsigned char sendWithSeq2[ANY_BUFFER_SIZE_AS_NEEDED];
    memset(sendWithSeq2,'\0',sizeof(sendWithSeq2));
    strcat(sendWithSeq2,BufContent);
    //wrong checksum obtained
    fwrite(sendWithSeq2,sizeof(unsigned char), BufContentSz, fout);

    //gives correct output
    fwrite(BufContent, sizeof(unsigned char), BufContentSz, fout2);
    memset(BufContent, '\0', sizeof(BufContent));

  }
```

The above is just a demo code I made to check where the issue was arising. The issue appears to be caused do to using an intermediate buffer. I have tried various buffer sizes, and even strcpy, sprintf to copy the buffer but it still didnt work.

NOTE: The same code works perfectly for a text file or even a csv file. Both output files have correct md5 checksum. And yes, I have tried opening files using both {r,w} and {rb,wb}.

Comment: In binary files `strlen` and `strcat` does not work as expected.  Because data contains `0`.

Comment: I figured that out after a little trial and error but sprintf also didnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `fwrite(BufContent, sizeof(unsigned char), BufContentSz, fout2);`

Comment: You can't use any of the string functions with binary data, so `strcat` is also not going to work. Your options are `memcpy` and `memmove`.

Comment: memcpy  worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    memset(BufContent, '\0', sizeof(BufContent));
    while ((BufContentSz = fread(BufContent, sizeof(unsigned char), FILE_BLOCK_SIZE, fin)) > 0) 
    {
        unsigned char sendWithSeq2[ANY_BUFFER_SIZE_AS_NEEDED];
        memset(sendWithSeq2,'\0',sizeof(sendWithSeq2));
        memcpy (sendWithSeq2,BufContent,BufContentSz);
        //wrong checksum obtained with strcat. Now works
        fwrite(sendWithSeq2,sizeof(unsigned char), BufContentSz, fout);

       //gives correct output
       fwrite(BufContent, sizeof(unsigned char), BufContentSz, fout2);
       memset(BufContent, '\0', sizeof(BufContent));

}
```

Replaced strcat with memcpy which makes md5 checksum correct